# Why do two ColdFusion 8 servers return different values with the same code?

Tags: image, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I have a piece of code that I am using to verify that an image is valid before attempting to scale it and add it to a PDF. Basically:

```
<cfset imgPath = "C:\uploads\images\myimage.jpg" />

<cfdump var="#IsImageFile(imgPath)#" />
```

I have the same image file on both servers and when I run the above code on both servers, one returns "YES", the other returns "NO" ("NO" is correct). Both servers are running ColdFusion 8 (Version 8,0,1,195765). The one returning "NO" is Developer Edition on Windows 7 64-bit, the other is Standard Edition on Windows 2003 SP2 32-bit. I can't see how the OS or Edition would have an effect on a simple piece of code like this. What could be causing this?

Thank you.

Results of Image Test Code:

Developer Edition on Windows 7 (64-bit):

```
GetReadableImageFormats: BMP,GIF,JFIF,JPEG,JPEG 2000,JPEG-LOSSLESS,JPEG-LS,JPEG2000,JPG,PNG,PNM,RAW,TIF,TIFF,WBMP 

GetWriteableImageFormats: BMP,GIF,JFIF,JPEG,JPEG 2000,JPEG-LOSSLESS,JPEG-LS,JPEG2000,JPG,PNG,PNM,RAW,TIF,TIFF,WBMP 

FileExists: YES 

IsImageFile: NO
```

Standard Edition on Windows 2003 (32-bit):

```
GetReadableImageFormats: BMP,GIF,JFIF,JPEG,JPEG 2000,JPEG-LOSSLESS,JPEG-LS,JPEG2000,JPG,PNG,PNM,RAW,TIF,TIFF,WBMP 

GetWriteableImageFormats: BMP,GIF,JFIF,JPEG,JPEG 2000,JPEG-LOSSLESS,JPEG-LS,JPEG2000,JPG,PNG,PNM,RAW,TIF,TIFF,WBMP 

FileExists: YES 

IsImageFile: YES
```

Comment: I now have both pieces of code pointing to the same exact file (not a copy of the original), and I'm getting the same result.

Comment: If you are using the developer edition are running it as a stand alone server e.g. localhost:8500, and you must be running II6 on your 2003 server, correct? Or are you running it on Apache?

Comment: Actually, Developer Edition is running on Windows 7 with IIS 6.

Comment: Try copying your Standard edition license to your Dev machine. If it still gives the same results, you can rule out differences between Dev Ed vs Standard. And be sure to remove that license when you're done!

Answer (score 1):

[From the documentation](http://cfdocs.org/isimagefile):

> Use this function to determine whether an image file is valid. This
>   function returns a False value if the image file format is not
>   supported by the server where ColdFusion is deployed, or if the
>   pathname to the image file is null or invalid.

It goes on to suggest

> To determine which image file formats are supported on the server where ColdFusion is deployed, use the [GetReadableImageFormats](http://cfdocs.org/getreadableimageformats) and [GetWriteableImageFormats](http://cfdocs.org/getwriteableimageformats).

I can't see where you've said which server is right and wrong however it seems that the problem is caused by the server rather than CF.

Check the results you get from the get*ImageFormats functions and see if that helps - although reading jpgs is probably baseline...

The other thing to check is the permissions that CF runs under on each server - if you are manually copying the file to the server you may have file access permissions interfering.

Answer (score 0):

Can you attach (or link to) the image here?  I'll do the same test on my systems... one Mac and the other Windows 2008.

Comment: Sorry, it's a private image that I'm not allowed to share. Needless to say, I know that the image is not valid, as when it passes through validation, it then throws an error when attempting to add it to the PDF. I'm  just wondering why it's viewed as valid on one server and invalid on another.

Comment: There is no error thrown. The page is returning "YES" on one server, and "NO" on the other.

Comment: I was referring to your comment that an error is thrown when "attempting to add it to the PDF". But see @Antony's comment above. I suspect he is on the right track.

Comment: From what I can tell, the image is a JPEG, but it is either progressive or CMYK, so the iText java library can't work with it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this may sound simplistic but if you swap IsImageFile with FileExists, do you get "yes" in both cases?

```
<cfdump var="#FileExists(imgPath)#" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You might check what version of Java is being used by CF.  There may be version differences and one has more features than the other.